# How can I search Craigslist for a phrase that includes quotation marks?

Tags: craigslist

I want to search Craigslist for a TV that is not 22 inches or 32 inches and isn't broken, etc.

So my query was: `tv|television -projection|plasma|apple|broken -22" -32"`.

Here is the [actual search](http://atlanta.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=tv%7Ctelevision%20-projection%7Cplasma%7Capple%7Cbroken%20-22%22%20-32%22&sort=rel&hasPic=1&search_distance=15&postal=30043&min_price=25&max_price=150).

But the double quotes is messing it up (because a pair of double quotes usually indicates a phrase).  I probably need to escape those special characters somehow.

[Craigslist Search Help](https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/search) does not specify what I'm doing wrong.

What search query will achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading Craigslist's Advance Search instructions, I don't think your search can be done. But I have a couple alternatives that might get you closer to the results you want.

1. Use wildcards instead of quotes:  `tv|television -projection|plasma|apple|broken -22* -32*`
2. Just omit the quotes: `tv|television -projection|plasma|apple|broken -22 -32`

Both of those queries do return results.  Unfortunately, they probably don't return some results that you would like to see (because of false positive matches).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a search engine such as [AllCraigslistsearch.com](http://allcraigslistsearch.com) and use regular Google boolean search operators. So your search query would look like this:

```
(tv|television) -(projection|plasma|apple|broken) -22 -32
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the wildcards "*" and "?"
I use the * for when i'm looking for particular size, ex people list memory size differently,  128  or 128gb or 128g or 128 gb.   I can search for 128* and all will list, whereas if i only search for 128 I won't get 128gb or 128g in my results.